Groupby and shift without using lambda function
I have a dataframe like so:
data = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', periods=14, freq='D'),
    'value': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
}

My actual dataframe contains millions of rows.
I sort the timestamp columns and so the ID column gets intersperesed when you look at the raw dataframe.
I want to groupby ID and find the difference between each row and the 3rd previous row.
I currently have it working like so:
# Sort by ID and timestamp
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestamp'])

# Group by 'ID' and calculate the difference with the 5th previous row
df['value_diff'] = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)['value'].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(3))

However since my actual dataframe is huge, it takes quite a bit of time. I also read that using lambda is slow.
Eventually I want to filter based on whether the value_diff column is increasing or decresing.
Typically I would use
inc_check=df['value'].diff(3).ge(0)
df=df[inc_check]

but it doesnt groupby to calculate the difference.
Is there a more elgant way to achieve this?

how many rows and groups do you have in your dataset?

@mozway millions of rows and probably hundreds of groups

Don't use apply, just go with groupby.shift directly and then subtract to the original column:
df['value_diff'] = df['value'] - df.groupby('ID')['value'].shift(3)

Or groupby.diff:
df['value_diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['value'].diff(3)

Output:
    ID  timestamp  value  value_diff
0    1 2023-01-01     11         NaN
1    1 2023-01-02     22         NaN
3    1 2023-01-04     44         NaN
5    1 2023-01-06     66        55.0
6    1 2023-01-07     77        55.0
10   1 2023-01-11     22       -22.0
13   1 2023-01-14     55       -11.0
2    2 2023-01-03     33         NaN
4    2 2023-01-05     55         NaN
7    2 2023-01-08     88         NaN
8    2 2023-01-09     99        66.0
9    2 2023-01-10     11       -44.0
11   2 2023-01-12     33       -55.0
12   2 2023-01-13     44       -55.0


Thank You for that suggestion. I was in the process of adding to my question when you submitted the answer :)
Is there a way i can do the groupby.shift and filter the dataframe in a single step without having to create a calculated column ?

Of course: out = df[df.groupby('ID')['value'].diff(3).ge(0)] should do the trick

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', periods=14, freq='D'),
    'value': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'timestamp'])

# Calculate the difference with the 3rd previous row
df['value_diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['value'].diff(3)

df['diff_trend'] = np.where(df['value_diff'] >= 0, 'increasing', 'decreasing')

# Drop rows where value_diff is NaN
df_filtered = df.dropna(subset=['value_diff'])

print(df_filtered)
"""
   ID  timestamp  value  value_diff  diff_trend
5    1 2023-01-06     66        55.0  increasing
6    1 2023-01-07     77        55.0  increasing
10   1 2023-01-11     22       -22.0  decreasing
13   1 2023-01-14     55       -11.0  decreasing
8    2 2023-01-09     99        66.0  increasing
9    2 2023-01-10     11       -44.0  decreasing
11   2 2023-01-12     33       -55.0  decreasing
12   2 2023-01-13     44       -55.0  decreasing
"""

